# Find area of square in circle (puzzle)

Tags: triangles, puzzle, area

Source of question : https://nrich.maths.org/548
Question=Find area of the shaded/inscribed part of the shape.
I have got the answer for the first two shaded shapes , however the I cannot find a way of finding the area of the second square . As the triangle is isoceles take the two equal sides as '3' and the hypotenuse as '3✓2)'
Picture of shape attached :

[image]

Comment: The words don't seem to match the picture.  Your title refers to a square in a circle, but there is no circle.  Your text refers to multiple squares but there is only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

remembering that $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles right angled triangle